# How to encrypt remote repo, with gcrypt or other?

Tags: git, bitbucket, gcrypt

The goal is to store my code encrypted on a BitBucket remote repo. Something should deal with encrypting and decrypting so I landed on gcrypt or in full, git-remote-gcrypt.

I have a Bitbucket account with SSH keys configured.
This is what I've tried.

### rsync

I copied these commands from the manual.

```bash
git remote remove cryptremote
git remote add cryptremote gcrypt::rsync://git@bitbucket.org/user/cryptremote.git
git config remote.cryptremote.gcrypt-participants "user"
git push cryptremote master
```

console:

> gcrypt: Repository not found: rsync://git@bitbucket.org/user/cryptremote.git
> gcrypt: Setting up new repository
> protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
> (see the rsync man page for an explanation)
> rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(600) [sender=v3.2.3]
> error: failed to push some refs to 'gcrypt::rsync://git@bitbucket.org/user/cryptremote.git'

Comment: `unable to look up bitbucket.org:user`.  Your URI is wrong, and should likely be `bitbucket.org/user`.  You may have more issues.

Comment: @StephenNewell For HTTPS links it's indeed /user but for Git links it's :user. At least, that's what I see when I look at the links provided to clone.

Comment: @progonkpa No, for `git://` protocol it's also `bitbucket.org/user`. Even for for `ssh://` protocol it's `bitbucket.org/user`. Only for scp-like URLs it's `git@bitbucket.org:user/cryptremote.git`. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#_git_urls

Comment: @phd the docs definitely say you're correct. In practice, BitBucket passes the SCP style link. At any rate, I tried with a slash, now it says 'connection refused'.

Comment: @progonkpa I tested and found I can connect to Bitbucket.org repositories using HTTPS, SSH and SCP-like but not with `git://` protocol. It seems all major Git hosters have dropped `git://` protocol as it's too insecure. Use one of the other 2 supported protocols (two because SSH and SCP-like are 2 different syntax for same protocol).

Comment: @phd ok, I'll clean up the question a bit and add some new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`freetalk@bitbucket.org`: I confirm this would never work, as an SSH URL to a Git remote repository hosting service would always use the '`git`' user (and rely on the SSH key to authenticate and identify the actual user account).

[`spwhitton/git-remote-gcrypt` commit 6233fde](https://github.com/spwhitton/git-remote-gcrypt/commit/6233fdebddd791d8cd03f5c8d570805451b44c5f) does mention:

> Remove deprecated `gcrypt::ssh://` (use rsync instead)

So a `rsync` URI seems more supported, as in [commit 3b69f81](https://github.com/spwhitton/git-remote-gcrypt/commit/3b69f816c9c371e935544b87cf2f321fdd795486)

In your case:

```
 gcrypt::rsync://git@bitbucket.org/user/cryptremote.git
                ^^^^^            ^^^
```

For any "`protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?`" error message, try and [put in your `.bashrc`](https://serverfault.com/a/805532/783):

```sh
# for non-interactive sessions stop execution here -- https://serverfault.com/a/805532/67528
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return
```

But check also a [possible `rsync` version mismatch](https://serverfault.com/a/1018066/783) (for instance, using a [Bitbucket pipeline](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/get-started-with-bitbucket-pipelines/) just to display `rsync` version).

As [illustrated here](https://superuser.com/q/1162907/141), if SSH is not working, a `gcrypt::https://user@bitbucket.org/user/test.git` HTTPS URL might work better.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Now I'm getting a rsync protocol error though. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: @progonkpa OK, I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I tried the [[ $- != *i* ]] && return. That line was already in my .bashrc and added it as the first line in .zshrc to be sure, but it didn't help. It works now over HTTPS which requires an App Password. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments, I got it to work over HTTPS.

I wrote a small tutorial for myself and for you.

---

## Encrypt remote Git repo with git-remote-gcrypt

### General Workflow

- generate GPG private and public key (GnuPG Linux)
- create a remote repo
- init a local repo
- configure remote and gcrypt (commands below)
- clone or push

### gcrypt example with rsync didn't work with Bitbucket

```bash
git remote add cryptremote gcrypt::rsync://git@bitbucket.org/USER/cryptremote.git
# gcrypt docs use :user but git usually uses /user format
# git remote add cryptremote gcrypt::rsync://git@bitbucket.org:USER/cryptremote.git
git config remote.cryptremote.gcrypt-participants "GPG_KEY_ID_OR_KEY_NAME"
git config remote.cryptremote.gcrypt-signingkey "GPG_KEY_ID_OR_KEY_NAME"
git push cryptremote master
```

> gcrypt: Repository not found: rsync://git@bitbucket.org/user/cryptremote.git
> gcrypt: Setting up new repository
> protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
> (see the rsync man page for an explanation)
> rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(600) [sender=v3.2.3]
> error: failed to push some refs to 'gcrypt::rsync://git@bitbucket.org/user/cryptremote.git'

### gcrypt over HTTPS

Template from man page, modified to HTTPS, example repo name 'cryptremote':

```bash
git init
git remote add origin gcrypt::https://USER:APP_PASSWD@bitbucket.org/USER/cryptremote.git
git config remote.origin.gcrypt-participants "GPG_KEY_ID_OR_KEY_NAME"
git config remote.origin.gcrypt-signingkey "GPG_KEY_ID_OR_KEY_NAME"
# removes GPG password prompts but makes the name of the key owner public
git config remote.origin.gcrypt-publish-participants true
# in case of an existing encrypted repo
git clone gcrypt::https://USER:APP_PASSWD@bitbucket.org/USER/cryptremote.git
# in case of starting a new encrypted remote repo
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

### Fix GPG password prompts during gcrypt push and pull

> man git-remote-gcrypt
>
> > gcrypt.publish-participants
> >
> > By  default, the gpg key ids of the participants are obscured by
> > encrypting using gpg -R. Setting this option  to  true  disables
> > that security measure.

---

Gratitude for something that works.

However, I don't like that I had to use HTTPS and an app password as Bitbucket now forces its users to use those for HTTPS.

Though I'm not sure why rsync isn't working, it seems the issue lies at Bitbucket as I use rsync flawlessly between my computer and my Android.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems the instructions vary and some indications do not even work; I started to try the various combinations of " : " vs " / " and "https" vs. "rsync" vs "git"....and finally found a combination that seems to work:

```
git remote add origin gcrypt::git@<URL>:<group>/test.git

git config remote.origin.gcrypt-participants "<my-key-id>"
git config remote.origin.gcrypt-signingkey "<my-key-id>"

git push -u origin alpha
gcrypt: Repository not found: git@<URL>:<group>/test.git
gcrypt: Setting up new repository
gcrypt: Remote ID is :id:<some hash>
gcrypt: Due to a longstanding bug, this push implicitly has --force.
gcrypt: Consider explicitly passing --force, and setting
gcrypt: gcrypt's require-explicit-force-push git config key.
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
gcrypt: Encrypting to:  -r <my-key-id>
gcrypt: Requesting manifest signature
remote: 
remote: To create a merge request for master, visit:
remote:   http://<URL>/<group>/test/-/merge_requests/new?merge_request%5Bsource_branch%5D=master
remote: 
To <URL>:<group>/test.git
 * [new branch]      alpha -> alpha
Branch 'alpha' set up to track remote branch 'alpha' from 'origin'.
```

When I go to the gitlab repo, I can see two new files with hex names.

But then, I try to clone the repo back and get the following error:

```
cd somewhere-else
git clone gcrypt::git@<URL>:<group>/test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
gpg: error reading key: No public key
```

What's the problem?
It was I who encrypted this a moment ago and now I cannot clone.

Any pointers?

Comment: 1. When I wrote that, I couldn't get it to work with SSH as protocol, only with HTTPS. I see you use SSH in your URL gcrypt::git, if it were HTTPS, it would be gcrypt::https. 2. I had to provide an app key in my URL which is total horseshit imo, regardless, I don't see that in your URL. 3. I see you have a group in there, can't say anything about that. This was my URL that worked gcrypt::https://USER:APP_PASSWD@bitbucket.org/USER/REPO_NAME.git

Comment: Thanks for our comments.

I kept at it, inspecting all files involved and found that my ~/.gitconfig has an old signing key under not under [gcrypt] section but under [user]; removed it altogether and things seem to be working.

Comment: Awesome you got it to work! I see I made a mistake in my previous comment, though not relevant for you at this point, for onreaders: The URL should be gcrypt::https://USER:APP... However, it seems @gsal perhaps got it working with SSH which would be my preference too.